# Zend Autoload of Model in PHPUnit

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm trying to write some test cases for a ZF application I'm writing but I can't seem get past this point.

I have extended the `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase`, adding the following:

```
public function setUp() {
    $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application('testing', 
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
    parent::setUp();
}
```

It works, and it initializes the Zend Autoloader, allowing me to load other classes inside my library as well as Zend classes. So I setup a test:

```
public function testUserUnauthorized() {
    $this->dispatch('/api/user');
    //Assertions...
}
```

Sadly, the test never gets past the dispatch. Instead, it gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'App_Model_User' not found in ....Action.php
```

Action.php is a class extending `Zend_Controller_Action`. In it, there is a function that uses `App_Model_User` to authenticate the logged in user. I never had to add a `require_once` since the Autoloader works. That's the strange part: it works through my browser. Just not in PHPUnit.

So I dumped the Autoloaders registered with the Zend Autoloader:

```
public function testUserUnauthorized() {
    print_r(Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->getAutoloaders());
    exit;
    $this->dispatch('/api/user');
}
```

It shows all my modules, as well as the namespaces for views, controllers, models, etc. I did the same through my browser and the dumps matched.

Comment: missing autoloader config? some custom spl autoloaders? find out which autoloader loads the App_Model_User class.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Autoloader needs App_ added as an autoload prefix for this to work as you expect, something like this:

```
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace("App_");
```

Comment: No joy. Seems to have no effect.

Comment: This fixed the issue that had been plaguing me for a good part of the day: thank you!  Part of the problem I've encountered is that many of the tutorials pertaining to ZF(1) and PHPUnit are at least 4 years old, and predate the more recent inclusion of Zend_Loader_Autoloader.  Your solution works great for ZF 1.12.3.